# Angular/Karma TypeError: Cannot Read Property 'offsetTop' of Undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

I wrote an angular directive to manipulate the DOM on scroll and now I am trying to write a test in Karma/Jasmine but I am having trouble getting even a simple test to pass, but I haven't been able to find a solution I could apply to my situation.

this is my directive:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('myApp.sticky', [])

.directive('sticky', ['$window', '$anchorScroll',
    function($window, $anchorScroll) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
      var atTop;
      scope.atTop = atTop;
      var stickyVal = elm.context.offsetTop;
      scope.sticky = function () {
        angular.element($window).bind("scroll", function() {
        if (angular.element($window).scrollTop() > stickyVal) {
          elm.css({position: 'fixed', top: '0px'});
          if (elm.children().length === 1) {
            elm.append(elm.next().next());
          }
          return true;
        } else {
          elm.css({position: 'static'});
          return false;
        }
      });
      };
      scope.sticky();
    }
  };
}]);
```

and this is what I have so far for my test:

```
'use strict';
describe('myApp.sticky module', function () {
  var scope,
  element,
  directive,
  compiled,
  html;

  beforeEach(function () {
    module('myApp.sticky');
    html = '<span sticky>test</span>';
    inject(function ($compile, $rootScope) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      element = angular.element(html);
      compiled = $compile(element);
      compiled(scope);
      scope.$digest();
    });
 });
  describe('sticky directive', function () {
    it('should exist', function () {
      expect(element).toBeDefined();
    });
    it('should set the element to a fixed position at a break point', 
      function () {
      });
    });
 });
```

and this is what my terminal is giving me:

```
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) myApp.sticky module sticky directive should exist FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined
    at link (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive.js:12:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6752:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6146:13)
    at publicLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6042:30)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:35:7)
    at Object.invoke (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3965:17)
    at workFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2177:20)
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2163:37)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:31:5)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2162:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:31:5)
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.10.1) myApp.sticky module sticky directive should set the element to a fixed position at a break point FAILED
TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of undefined
    at link (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive.js:12:34)
    at nodeLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6752:13)
    at compositeLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6146:13)
    at publicLinkFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:6042:30)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:35:7)
    at Object.invoke (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js:3965:17)
    at workFn (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2177:20)
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2163:37)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:31:5)
Error: Declaration Location
    at window.inject.angular.mock.inject (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js:2162:25)
    at null.<anonymous> (/Users/meredithcapone/src/StickyChallenge/app/components/sticky/sticky-directive_test.js:31:5)
Chrome 40.0.2214 (Mac OS X 10.10.1): Executed 3 of 3 (2 FAILED) (0.378 secs / 0.025 secs)
```

and this is my conf file:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(config){
  config.set({

    basePath : '../',

    files : [
      'app/bower_components/jquery/jquery.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-route/angular-route.js',
      'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
      'app/components/sticky/sticky-directive.js',
      'app/view1/view1.js',
      'app/app.js'
    ],

    autoWatch : true,

    frameworks: ['jasmine'],

    browsers : ['Chrome'],

    plugins : [
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-firefox-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine'
        ],

    junitReporter : {
      outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
      suite: 'unit'
    }

  });
};
```

any help would be very much appreciated.

thanks

update: I've been able to get my code to throw the same error by commenting out the reference to jquery in my html file, so I wonder if there's a dependency that karma isn't getting or that is in the wrong order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is 'context'? I don't know how that would work since elm should be the raw DOM node.

```
  var stickyVal = elm.context.offsetTop;
```

Change that line to:

```
var stickyVal = elm.offsetTop
```